# No module named influxdb

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, influxdb

i tried to install an grafana dashboard to manage temperature measured on ds18b20 sensors.
I found this tutorial: https://www.circuits.dk/temperature-logger-running-on-raspberry-pi/
Everything worked fine until `python templogger.py. -db=temp_logger_db -sn=test1`. Of course, i did installed influxdb but now it says i didn't installed influx db. Maybe an issue with my python?

Comment: Are you tried `pip install influxdb` ?

Comment: Of course, i did pip and pip3 were both successful installed as the terminal says

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do to figure out why python throws an Error saying influxdb not found.

**First:**

Did you install using python3 or python2. As there are usually two python versions installed in most systems. So "python" and "python3" will invoke different python versions.

From the Tutorial that you mentioned I can see that, *To run the script* you invoke following command:

```
python templogger.py. -db=temp_logger_db -sn=test1
```

By running using "python" keyword, it will look for modules like influxdb in python2's package directory.

So, you want to run your script as

```
python3 templogger.py. -db=temp_logger_db -sn=test1
```

**Second:**

If you want to use "python" also known as python2 version then you would have to install fluxdb using following command

```
python -m pip install fluxdb
```

Then you can run the script using following command:

```
python templogger.py. -db=temp_logger_db -sn=test1
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I did all these things before. But when i run: `dpkg --get-selections | grep python3` influxdb is not there.

Comment: try installing python3 first then, run the script again.

To install python type 


`sudo apt install python3`